# Trouble counting rows

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, outer-join

I'm using a calendar table as a join table and trying to create a chart for the number of reviews an employee would have received from a CMS.  The query currently looks like this

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(Calendar.datefield) AS Month, COUNT(Review.reviewee_id) AS Count
FROM calendar Calendar 
LEFT JOIN reviews Review ON MONTH(Calendar.datefield) = MONTH(Review.created) AND Review.reviewee_id = 24 AND YEAR(Calendar.datefield) = '2011'
GROUP BY Month
ORDER BY MONTH(Calendar.datefield)
```

This returns

```
'January', '0'
'February', '0'
'March', '0'
'April', '0'
'May', '0'
'June', '0'
'July', '0'
'August', '0'
'September', '0'
'October', '434'
'November', '120'
'December', '0'
```

But the counting is wrong.  I'm trying to understand the way the counting is working.  It is correct as far as 0 for each month, but for October this employee only had 4 reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should replace
  `MONTH(Calendar.datefield) = MONTH(Review.created)`
with
  `Calendar.datefield = Review.created`

Without that replacement, you count *all* reviews that happened in a specific Month (for example October), not only those for a specific Month in 2011, but also, for example those in October 2010.

Comment: That's it.  I also checked on Jon's suggestion. It was looping through each day in the month.  So October actually had 14 reviews (I was wrong) and multiplied that by 31 days in the month to get 434.  Thanks for the quick help to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is happening you can try some simpler queries. First try taking out the GROUP BY and get the list of everything it is counting.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(Calendar.datefield) AS Month, Review.reviewee_id, *
FROM calendar Calendar 
LEFT JOIN reviews Review ON MONTH(Calendar.datefield) = MONTH(Review.created) 
AND Review.reviewee_id = 24 AND YEAR(Calendar.datefield) = '2011'
AND MONTHNAME(Calendar.datefield) = 'October'
```

The most likely thing is that multiple rows are linking, but 434 does not work out evenly in 4's which is odd.